# MySQL Slave not updated

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

This might be a duplicate of questions on the same problem asked before. But all the suggestions to the previous questions do not seem to work in my case.
I have set up Replication using SSH Tunnel. Any changes on Master are being logged in the mysqld-relay-bin file on the slave. But the SQL thread does not seem to be executing these queries as Slave is not being updated.

A replication user has been created with host as 127.0.0.1 and granted the replication slave privilege. For testing purpose, I've run the following command to establish the SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -f tom@abc.com -L 7306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

I can successfully login into the remote server's db using

```
 mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 4306
```

Below are the outputs of SHOW MASTER STATUS, SHOW SLAVE STATUS, SHOW PROCESSLIST respectively:

```
mysql> show master status
    -> ;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000008 |      366 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: replication_user
                  Master_Port: 7306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000008
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 366
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000019
                Relay_Log_Pos: 382
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000008
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: zo_dev_matrix.*
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 366
              Relay_Log_Space: 539
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show processlist;
+----+-------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Id | User        | Host            | db            | Command | Time | State                                                                       | Info             |
+----+-------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|  1 | system user |                 | NULL          | Connect |  421 | Waiting for master to send event                                            | NULL             |
|  2 | system user |                 | NULL          | Connect |   61 | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it | NULL             |
|  8 | root        | localhost:33078 | NULL          | Sleep   |    2 |                                                                             | NULL             |
| 82 | root        | localhost:33081 | NULL          | Sleep   |  352 |                                                                             | NULL             |
| 83 | root        | localhost:33082 | zo_dev_matrix | Sleep   |  348 |                                                                             | NULL             |
| 84 | root        | localhost:33083 | zo_dev_matrix | Sleep   |  346 |                                                                             | NULL             |
| 86 | root        | localhost       | NULL          | Query   |    0 | NULL                                                                        | show processlist |
+----+-------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

The replication filter you have in place

```
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: zo_dev_matrix.*
```

is actually a little misleading. In the MySQL Documentation, the legal characters for wildcards are `%`, `_` and `\_`. (If you want to interpret a literal underscore). The asterisk character is not listed. The above filter is actually looking for a table called `zo_dev_matrix.*`. Therefore, you have two options

## OPTION #1

Correct the filter in `my.cnf` to have this

```
[mysqld]
replicate_wild_do_table = zo_dev_matrix.%
```

## OPTION #2

Change the filter to the database `zo_dev_matrix`

```
replicate_do_db = zo_dev_matrix
```

only if all your queries do no preface the table with the db and you explicit set the current database to zo_dev_matrix.

## CAVEAT

With MySQL 5.6 and back, you must restart mysql after changing the filter in `my.cnf`. [Starting with MySQL 5.7, you can create a dynamic replication filter so a mysql restart is not necessary.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-replication-filter.html)

Comment: Hi Rolando. Thanks for the detailed response. I will try Option 1. Option 2 did not work for me. Hence I went for replicate_wild_do_table. There is only one database on the master i.e. zo_dev_matrix. On Slave, there are several databases but I'm not sure how do you set the current database. Initially, I used replicate-rewrite-db which didnt work. Then just for testing, I created the zo_dev_matrix on slave too. It looks like not having the current database set could be the problem. But I do not know how do you do that as the database is accessed by an app.

Comment: And it works just like that. Changed * to %. Restarted the server. Stopped slave, Changed the master_log_pos and master_log_file, started slave. It worked. Then I replaced replicate_wild with replicate_do and it also worked. This was not working before with the value "zo_dev_matrix.opportunity". But now everything seems to be working perfectly. Previously an error was thrown that a certain second table does not exist. I could see the insert query for the table in the relay log. That table still does not exist. I wonder why it is not throwing an error now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have a successful connection from the slave to the master, and the SQL thread is running. But I notice this:

```
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: zo_dev_matrix.*
```

This indicates you have configured a [replication filter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-rules.html). It means that even though the relay logs contain all changes, only changes applying to tables in the `zo_dev_matrix` database will be executed on the slave. If your changes are in other databases, for example the `test` database, it won't show up on the slave.

---

*Update:*

If you refer to the [documentation for replicate-wild-do-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table), the wildcard it uses is `%`, not `*`.

Oh, never mind, I see Rolando already answered that. :-)

Comment: There are no other databases on the master Bill. There is only one database.

Comment: @Ravi, there's always a `mysql` database, and usually a `test` database by default. There are also the system databases `information_schema` and `performance_schema`, but these are never replicated anyway.

Comment: sorry I meant there is only one database that is used by the application.